Nativescript issue with the cli version install
I've got a CLI version problem.
I did uninstall of nativescript package npm uninstall nativescript with and without -g, but when I do a tns info it still shows a version installed.
I found the location of tns using type command.
But curious why npm uninstall -g nativescript doesn't install it.
How can I delete it manually?
There's a tns link in ~/.npm-global/bin
tns -> ../lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
and then there's the files in the ../lib/node_modules folder.
